# How do I save table updates to file using triggers in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Im trying to save all updates to a table in a file using a trigger and the "INTO OUTFILE" statement to no avail.

```
DELIMITER // 
CREATE TRIGGER test_trigger AFTER INSERT ON employee 
BEGIN 
  SET @tess = CONCAT("{old:", OLD, ",new:", NEW, ",timestamp:", NOW(), "}"); 
  @tess INTO OUTFILE "~/Desktop/test.txt" 
END; 
DELIMITER;
```

I know very little sql but based off my research the syntax is correct. Maybe the action is not possible in mysql? All examples I've seen use the "INTO OUTFILE" statement within a "SELECT" statement.

Comment: Why not creating a log table and use the trigger to update the table ? You can query the table as you wish , It seems useless to me exporting every change to a log file

Comment: Consider putting it in a table instead as JSON. Look into "audit logs" for SQL. For example, look at how [paper_trail](https://github.com/paper-trail-gem/paper_trail) stores changes.

Comment: @ErgestBasha I wish to trigger a notification as soon as event happens in db. The goal was to watch the log file for changes and act on that change

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems with your example.

- `SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE` only works when you use it as a clause of a SELECT statement. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select-into.html
- You can only use `INTO OUTFILE` to write to a file if the file does not exist. In other words, you can't append to an existing file with that statement. The manual says: *"**file_name** cannot be an existing file, which among other things prevents files such as /etc/passwd and database tables from being modified."* This means your trigger would only work for the very first update, and then it would start failing.
- You would have to implement three triggers for every table.
- I recommend against doing this in a trigger anyway, because a trigger executes before the transaction is committed. The transaction might subsequently be rolled back, but whatever you wrote to the file would not be rolled back. Therefore you could have a file full of updates that were never committed, which would be confusing.

Instead, I suggest you look into using MySQL's audit log plugin feature. MySQL Enterprise comes with an implementation of the audit log: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/audit-log.html

You can also get an open source implementation of the MySQL audit log. There are a few different implementations:

- https://www.percona.com/blog/2016/02/15/mysql-mariadb-with-mariadb-auditing-plugin/
- https://github.com/mcafee-enterprise/mysql-audit
- https://github.com/aws/audit-plugin-for-mysql